# How to make camera see long distances

Tags: camera

I want the camera to see things that are far away. Ive tried increasing the clip but that does nothing. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried to change the clipping value of the camera (and not of the scene) in the Properties panel > Data > Lens > Clipping?

Comment: @moonboots there's no Data panel in properties panel(n), I am using beta, is that panel moved somewhere else? I had the same problem "How to make camera see long distances", but I moved my objects closer to fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Im new to the animation world, also programs like this and ive been having so much trouble lately trying to figure it all out. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @user68982 Please Accept the answer below if this has solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

In 2.8, select your camera, then go in the *Properties* panel (on the right by default), select the *Object Data* tab (camera icon) > *Lens* > *Clip End*.

Comment: Okay... I am on!